# Why does `IsEmpty` write a dummy warning when called with a test object while a recovery scenario is active?

Tags: qtp

Very strange symptom:

Create a test with the following content and no associated libraries:

```
Print IsEmpty (Browser("index:=0"))
```

The point is to call `IsEmpty` with any test object.

Result when executed: The obvious (and expected), it prints: "`false`" (provides you have at least one window open on your desktop).

Run result looks fine in the viewer, like this:

[image: Run result as expected]

Now create a function library with the following content:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MyFunc(Object, MethodName, Arguments, RetVal)
    Print "Welcome."
End Function
```

Do *not* associate this library with the test.

Create a recovery scenario with the following properties:

```
Trigger: Test run error
    Error: Any error
Recovery operation: Function call
    Library: The one you just created
    Function to call: MyFunc
Post-Recovery Test Run Options:
    Process to next action or component iteration
```

Associate the recovery scenario to the test you created in the beginning. Set "`Activate Recovery scenarios:`" to "`On error`".

Run the test. The output is as expected, but the run result looks like this:

[image: Run result with warning]

The "Error" node has the following details ("Element nicht gefunden" is german and means "Element not found", I am very surprised to see a localized error message here):

[image: "Error" node detail]

How´s that? It appears that `IsEmpty` generates such an entry whenever it is called with a test object.

Could it be this is a bug?

My current workaround is to introduce my own `IsEmpty` function which disables the recovery scenario, calls the original `IsEmpty` function, and re-enables the recovery scenario.
Which is a horror, because the `IsEmpty` replacement cannot be named `IsEmpty`. That would result in a recursive call, because I cannot call the original version from the replacement if it has the same name (or can I?). And calling something different when you want to call `IsEmpty` is easily forgotten.

I cannot live with the warnings generated for every `IsEmpty` call if a recovery scenario is active.

**What´s going on? 
Can you guys reproduce this?
Is there a better workaround?**

English (of course) QTP 11.00 build 1018 with .net, ActiveX, Delphi, Java, Oracle, Silverlight, Web, Web Services and WPF add-ins, but none of them active for this demo. Using Hotfixes QTPWEB_00078 and QTPJV_00044. Windows 7.

**Update:** I just figured I can check for `VarType (Obj) = vbEmpty`, so I can create an `IsEmpty` replacement as outlined, but named `IsEmpty`. I.e. I have a workaround, but still am wondering if this is a QTP bug.

**Update 2:** The VarType (Obj) reference does not work, it generates the same strange run result warning.

**Update 3:** It seems IsEmpty cannot be replaced by a function with the same name. It The intrinsic function is always called.

**Update 4:** The closest one can come to replacing an intrinsic is the method outlined in http://www.knowledgeinbox.com/articles/qtp/advanced-qtp/overriding-default-functions-using-function-pointers/, but it requires a declaration and an assignment in every action script. Sigh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the question "How can I override intrinsic functions?" contained in my question, I **found a 1:1 replacement for the IsEmpty functionality that does not create this strange log entry with test objects**:

Instead of

```
IsEmpty (P)
```

use

```
TypeName (P) = "Empty"
```

If `P` is a test object, the `IsEmpty` call would create the magic log entry, while `TypeName` doesn't.

And this sure (imho) is a bug in QTP´s recovery scenario functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if `IsEmpty` works with not existing QTP objects, or that you are exploring "undefined behaviour" where everything can happen, from inconsistent return values to a format of you hard drive (while the latter is somewhat less probable than the first).

`IsEmpty` is normally used for uninitialize variables:

```
Dim a
MsgBox isEmpty(a)  ' --> True
a = ""
MsgBox isEmpty(a)  ' --> False
MsgBox isEmpty(b)  ' --> True or an Error if you use the error resume next statement

Dim obj : set obj = Nothing
MsgBox isEmpty(obj) ' --> False, it contains an object (Nothing is an object)
```

In QTP, I would recommend to use `Browser("index:=0").Exist(0)` to see if an object exists and not `IsEmpty`

Comment: Yeah. But what happens if you have an optional test object reference receives as a function parameter? If it´s empty, there is no test object. If it´s not, there must be one. Then, there is no test object to test for existence.

Comment: Since IsEmpty does not seem to work for certain, test object references my current workaround is to maintain a Boolean flag for the "testobject present" state. (And yes, I know about the difference between IsEmpty, is nothing, IsNull, etc.)

Comment: When I use optional function parameters that can contain an object, I test on `IsObject` and `Not Is Nothing`. When both criteria are met, I know the parameter wasn't used as optional.

Comment: This is fine if you pass Nothing. If you pass/receive Empty, you are back to IsEmpty.